# Pod install is no longer working in one of my react-native projects

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, cocoapods, rbenv

I was working on a react-native app a few months back, I've just resumed work on it and I'm having issues with pod install.
In the meantime, I've been working on other projects while this was on pause and pod install works just fine so this would suggest this is not an environment issue.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Ignoring json-2.6.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json -- 
    version 2.6.3
 <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require': dlopen(/Users/plafferty/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_rb_empty_keyword_given_p' - /Users/plafferty/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError)
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from /Users/plafferty/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/time.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:88:in `require'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to run the command mentioned in the first line of the error message `gem pristine json --version 2.6.3`? What happened when you did?

Comment: @spickermann, yes I did.
I have run both commands and nothing has worked.

I have also uninstalled my entire react-native dev env and I've reinstalled it.
I've still not had any luck.

Comment: Please make an effort to format posts that you create on StackOverflow. I have edited this post for you to make the error message that you received readable. There is [a Help Center article on formatting posts with markdown and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) that I encourage you to read. Posts that are illegible are less likely to receive replies because they are hard to read and indicate that you aren't willing to put in effort for your own question.

Comment: @anothermh, thanks for sorting this.
I do normally make an effort to format my questions properly (you'll be able to see this in all my other questions) and on this occasion I tried as well but I was experiencing issues with the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself.
I don't fully understand why it was working for some projects and not other - perhaps one of you could add to this.

In short, I made sure I only had one ruby version installed in my system.
There was multiple 2 versions conflicting with each other with no virtual control to manage the active version.